# Wordpress Skitter Slideshow - Control the animation of the labels in Skitter slideshow

Tags: jquery, wordpress, plugins, slideshow, skitter-slider

I am using slideshow plugin called SKitter for wordpress.

The slideshow displays an image with label mentioning any description for an image. The label
animate in (out) on change of an image.

Is there anyway to control the animation of the labels?

Basically, I want the strip on which the label gets displayed to remain intact even if the image gets changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this css code below tweek the height property

```
.box_skitter .label_skitter {
z-index: 99999;
position: absolute;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
color: #fff;
display: block!important;
opacity: 0.8;
background: #000;
height: 44px !important;
}
```